# Define a name with all row numbers of matching criteria using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

How can I get a table range with the row numbers of cells that have "Option_A" inside of the table below?

```
Type
Option_A
Option_A
Option_D
Option_A
```

In this case, I want to get a defined name that would return the following:

```
1
2
4
```

I'm using Openoffice Calc and until now, I tried to define a name as `MATCH("Option_A";A2:A9;0)` but it did not work because `MATCH` was only returning the first occurrence.

So, what is the formula that can give me the above result?

**EDIT**

So, as asked, I have the values on A2:A9 and I want to display the results on C1:C8.
Here's what I want from the example above on my worksheet:

```
    A           B   C
1   Type            1
2   Option_A        2
3   Option_A        4
4   Option_D
5   Option_A
```

On the left are the row numbers of the sheet and on top are the columns.

Comment: Could you describe where would you exactly want those values? In which cell(s) for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to get the results you're looking for (it works in MS-Excel-2007 at least):

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$5="Option_A",ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1),ROWS($B$1:B1)),"")
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to use it, instead of pressing only <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the formula.

`IF($A$2:$A$5="Option_A",ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1)` gives the row number of the cells matching `Option_A`.

`SMALL` then take the smallest row in the first cell, the second smallest in the second cell, etc.

`IFERROR` is used to put blanks if ever there are no more `Option_A`, instead of outputting errors.

Comment: I imported it to OpenOffice Calc and it almost works fine. The only problem is that `IFERROR` is not recognized. Can you give me an alternative to that?

Comment: @CristianoSantos Sure. You can use `ISERROR` with `IF` as workaround: `=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$5="Option_A",ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1),ROWS($B$1:B1))),"",SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$5="Option_A",ROW($A$2:$A$5)-1),ROWS($B$1:B1)))`. Though it might be simpler to just drop the case of when there's an error and stop copying down the formula as soon as you get the first error in that case.

Comment: Oh wait, my mistake, this is not returning 1,2,4 but 1,2,"",4. How can I adpat it to return 1,2,4?

Comment: @CristianoSantos Weird. It's working fine on excel, see [the screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CLOcO.png)

Comment: Well I'm putting this on C3: `=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9="Option_A";ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1);ROWS($B$1:B3)));"";SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9="Option_A";ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1);ROWS($B$1:B3)))` and it prints "" instead of the 4

Comment: @CristianoSantos Okay, it might be by design in OpenOffice. Try using this instead? `=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9="Option_A";ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1;9^99);ROWS($B$1:B3)));"";‌​SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9="Option_A";ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1);ROWS($B$1:B3)))` I added an else clause in the `IF` which gives `9^99` if `Option_A` doesn't match.

Comment: Did not work. Here's [a screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/gl0ggarkz/). On column C I put the new formula that you said. On column E I used the previous formula. And in any case, If I move the code to the 1st row, I get 2,3,"",5.

Comment: @CristianoSantos Hm, in your screenshot, you haven't entered the formula as array formula. Did you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after copying the formula?

Comment: Ok, I tried it before but it did not work. Now it is on array formula. but, it only worked for C1. How do I put it on the other cells? I tried to use the fill down option but then I get 1,1,1,1.

Comment: @CristianoSantos Try deleting all the other values and re-filling the formula down? It happens if you fill all the cells with the formula with Ctrl+Enter sometimes and the other cells get locked. So, delete everything, put the array formula in C1, then fill down. If that doesn't work, I don't know... I just can say that it works on excel.

Comment: Ah, forget that, I found out that on OpenOffice Calc the fill down for array formulas only work if we press the CTRL key while filling down. Now it worked! Even with the other formula that does not have the `9^99`. So, the final working solution for openoffice is: `=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9="Option_A";ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1);ROWS($B$1:B1)));"";SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$9="Option_A";ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1);ROWS($B$1:B1)))` as array formula.

Comment: @CristianoSantos Awesome! :D